# What is the best way to reduce the size of a image that's going to be stored in SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, image, converters

Hi my ide is to store photos in an SQL Database and i want to konw how I can do to reduce the size of an image so that it dosnt take up so much space in the database. Shuld I use an alternative to SQL database or?

this is my current code that i use to convert and insert the image.

```
    byte[] img = null;
    int x,i;
    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        FileStream fs = new FileStream(imgloc,FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(fs);
        img = reader.ReadBytes((int)fs.Length);

        try
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Staff(id,Username,Password,Image) VALUES(@ID,'Nasar',0,@nasar)",connection);
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@nasar", img));
            command.Parameters.Add("@ID",i);

            connection.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("An Error has accured! Please send this message to support (" + ex.Message + ")");
            if(ex != null)
            {
                x = 1;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (connection != null)
            {
                connection.Close();
            }

            if (x == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Image has been recorded");
                i++;
            }


        }
    }
```

Comment: The best way to store an image in a database is to not store the image in the database. Store the image itself in the filesystem, store the metadata of the image in the database.

Comment: depending on the version of sql server, you may also use [filestream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg471497.aspx)

Comment: Having worked in EDRM for many years, there are cases when you should store images in the database but.. The database is often on expensive disks and requires full backups unless your considering this and more don't do it . I would consider azure blob, file system or look at the filestream stuff in SQL. You could compress the image but it's likely that its compressed all ready,you could reduce the resolution but that is probably unacceptable

Comment: Thank you guys for the quick response, I've been thinking about a URL but i dont know if its a good way, simplest way i know is to store it in a offline SQL but there will be multiple users that will need to acsess the files so that would lead to others having files that others dont have. So what about an URL link to the photos

Comment: you can reduce the size of the image programatically, you need to make it into a .net image and using the graphics library you can process it into lower size, lower quality, more efficient image type - at the moment your data is a stream of bytes, and we have no info on what type of image file it is.  Are they going to be .bmp or .jpg for example?  If they are .bmp and you want a lossless format, then you could use .png - processing change can be done in .net

Comment: I did store images in a database as an experiment, if you are not a commercial operation, then I wouldn't be put off from experimenting with images in a database on the grounds of cost etc, in any case it can also have various advantages over storing images in folders, for example a windows file system folder becomes very slow when file numbers in it becomes large, maybe as low as about 500 files.  Creating endless subdirectories programatically is a tricky task, and is open to be meddled with by any user who comes along and sees it.

Comment: If you put the images on a web site, and then the data stored in SQL server is a url to that image, it then means that the images can be seen by anyone who knows or guesses the url.  If you get your web-application to retrieve the image from the DB then stream it out to an authorised user, then it is possible to place security on the image.  You can still do that without SQL though, for example you could hold image files on a folder not on the web, and then retrieve and stream out file contents.

Comment: Thanks guys for your replies but I think that as for now i will go with Database since its the best way for the moment since the database wont be that large if it becomes to large I will probably go with an URL Trough password protection should solve the all can see issue